# Formar lista de listas de parejas de elementos de manera aleatoria y sin repetición

Tags: python, python-2.7, algoritmos

Tengo un modelo que simula una comunidad de 8 agentes en parejas. Quiero crear una lista de 7 listas consecutivas de tal manera que todos los agentes queden emparejados con todos los agentes. Algo así, por ejemplo:

```
[[(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8)],
 [(1, 3), (2, 4), (5, 7), (6, 8)],
 [(1, 4), (2, 3), (5, 8), (6, 7)],
 [(1, 5), (2, 6), (3, 7), (4, 8)],
 [(1, 6), (3, 8), (5, 2), (7, 4)],
 [(1, 7), (2, 8), (3, 5), (4, 6)],
 [(1, 8), (3, 6), (5, 4), (7, 2)]]
```

He creado una función que genera las 7 listas, pero me falta incorporar que no haya repetición para asegurar que cada agente se empareja con cada agente solo una vez.

```
import random
agents = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
def group(agents):
    pairs = []
    for round in range(7):
        random.shuffle(agents)
        gen = zip(*[iter(agents)]*2)
        pairs.append(gen)
    return pairs
print (group(agents))
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien... tal como generas cada "gen", te aseguras de que dentro de él no haya repeticiones, pues son los 8 agentes "mezclados". ¿Te refieres por tanto a asegurar que no haya parejas repetidas entre diferentes "gen"? O sea, que en la matriz que representas como ejemplo no pueda aparecer una misma pareja en dos filas diferentes?. Y en ese caso ¿se considera la pareja (3,2) igual o diferente a la pareja (2,3)?

Comment: Exacto @abulafia, me refiero a que no haya parejas repetidas entre diferentes "gen". Y sí, pareja (2,3) es igual a (3,2). Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo primero que se me ocurrió fue ir guardando en un conjunto todas las parejas que se iban formando en cada "gen", y rechazar las "gen" que tuvieran intersecciones con ese conjunto. De este modo una nueva "gen" sólo se añade a la lista `pairs` si no tiene intersección con el conjunto de parejas generadas anteriormente.

Para que la pareja `(3,2)` se considere igual a la `(2,3)`, se ordena antes de meterla al conjunto de parejas ya vistas, y así ambas se convierten al "mismo" elemento `(2,3)`.

Esta función implementa esa idea:

```
import random
agents = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

def group(agents, n=7):
    pairs = []
    generadas = set()   # Conjunto con todas las parejas ya generadas

    while len(pairs) < n:
        random.shuffle(agents)
        gen = zip(*[iter(agents)]*2)
        # Convertir esta "gen" en un conjunto formado por sus parejas
        # cada una de ellas ordenada
        cjto = { tuple(sorted(pair)) for pair in gen }

        # Si no hay intersección con las ya generadas
        if not cjto & generadas:
          pairs.append(gen)          # Añadirlo al resultado
          generadas.update(cjto)     # y al conjunto
    return pairs
```

Ejemplo de salida producida:

```
[[(1, 7), (2, 6), (4, 5), (3, 8)], 
 [(1, 8), (7, 3), (2, 4), (5, 6)], 
 [(8, 6), (4, 1), (3, 2), (5, 7)], 
 [(4, 3), (7, 2), (5, 8), (1, 6)], 
 [(3, 5), (8, 4), (7, 6), (2, 1)], 
 [(3, 1), (7, 8), (6, 4), (5, 2)], 
 [(1, 5), (2, 8), (4, 7), (3, 6)]]
```

Aunque el método produce resultados correctos, en la práctica es **bastante ineficiente** ya que, a medida que se añaden casos al resultado, cada vez es más difícil encontrar nuevos casos que no tengan intersecciones con las parejas ya generadas. Modificando ligeramente el código anterior pueden contarse cuántos "intentos fallidos" tiene que hacer antes de encontrar 7 que funcionen. Me salen alrededor de 300 intentos fallidos para conseguir 7 con éxito.

No obstante eso no debería suponer mucho tiempo, y si bien en mi ordenador termina en dos centésimas de segundo, por alguna razón desconocida el mismo código ejecutado en Collaboratory no acaba jamás (lo he dejado varios minutos).

### Otra alternativa

Esta alternativa puede que sea más ineficiente, pero al menos tiene un tiempo de ejecución determinista, pues no depende de colisiones aleatorias.

Se trata de generar de antemano todos los "gen" posibles, para después tomar al azar 7 de ellos.

La generación de esos "gen" la hago usando todas las permutaciones de los agentes (con `itertools.permutations`), para después convertir cada permutación en una tupla ordenada de tuplas ordenadas. Así dos permutaciones en aparriencia diferentes como `12345678` y `78124365`, una vez ordenada cada pareja y éstas dentro del gen, dan lugar ambas a la misma tupla: `((1,2), (3,4), (5,6), (7,8))`. Estas tuplas las voy metiendo a un conjunto y de ese modo me aseguro de que cada una de las que es "única" aparece una sola vez.

Finalmente convierto el conjunto resultante en lista, para hacerle un `shuffle()`  y tomar 7 elementos.

Este es el código:

```
from itertools import permutations
import random

def group(agents, n=7):
  todos = set()
  for caso in permutations(agents):
      gen = zip(*[iter(caso)]*2)
      gen = tuple(sorted(tuple(sorted(pair)) for pair in gen))
      todos.add(gen)
  todos = list(todos)
  random.shuffle(todos)
  return todos[:n]

agents = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
print(group(agents))
```

En mi máquina este tarda bastante más que el primero (unas tres décimas de segundo, que no es gran cosa, pero es un orden de magnitud). Pero en Colaboratory también termina rápido. El tiempo de ejecución es más determinista.

Y la ventaja es que éste escala mucho mejor si en vez de 7 filas queremos por ejemplo 20. Como ya tenemos pre-generados todos los casos (y he contado que son 105), lo mismo nos da extraer 7 que 70. En el primer algoritmo en cambio, cuantas más filas queramos, más tardará pues más colisiones se irán produciendo a medida que generamos casos.

Comment: Ingeniosa respuesta @abulafia. Muchas gracias. ¿Me equivoco si digo que el resultado que arroja el segundo método es una lista que contiene tuplas de tuplas, en lugar de una lista de listas?

Comment: Sí, tal como está hecho lo que retorna `group()` es una lista cuyos elementos son tuplas de tuplas. Sería sencillo hacer que fuera una lista de listas de tuplas, si lo prefieres así.

Comment: Sí. Muchas gracias @abulafia. Sería algo así: lista_de_listas = [list(elem) for elem in group(agents)]